# Android spinner item selected default doesn't work

Tags: android, spinner, onitemselectedlistener

in my app i have develop a filter fragment. In this fragment i have a checkbox with spinner list that if is a item selected he apply a filter on a json.
Now this filter works fine if when app start is not check, but if i set checked by default not apply a filter
this is my code:
I have a flag with 0/1 value to set On Off checkbox:

```
public static int flag_position=1; // checkbox On when app start
```

and this code about spinner:

```
Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> positionAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            getActivity(), R.array.array_name, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
    positionAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
    spinner1.setAdapter(positionAdapter);
    spinner1.setSelection(Lista.flag_distance=5);

spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
            // your code here
            Lista.flag_distance=position;
            Log.d("Car2go_flagqqq", String.valueOf(position));
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
            // your code here
        }

    });
```

when app run the checkbox is On and item of spinner is set, but the filter is not apply on service. Instead if i click checkbox to Off and after again to On, he works.
How i can works onItemSelected by default when start app?

Thanks

Comment: Set your listener _before_ setting the selection.

Comment: Can you explain me how?

Comment: Call `setSelection()` _after_ calling `setOnItemSelectedListener()`

Comment: I have try this but doesn't work

Comment: this method works only when i call filter fragment that contain the spinner. When i run app the first view is a map and only after clicked on filter fragment on map the filter works